# Problem with rake jobs:work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, merb

while i am running rake jobs:work.

I am getting this error.

```
** Invoke jobs:work (first_time)
** Invoke merb_env (first_time)
** Execute merb_env
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Delayed
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
C:/cyncabc/config/initializers/delayed_job.rb:1
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:622:in `load_application_initializers'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `each'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `load_application_initializers'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:176:in `process'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
C:/cyncabc/config/environment.rb:9
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'   
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
C: /ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
C:/ruby/bin/rake:19:in `load'
C:/ruby/bin/rake:19
```

Comment: can you say us more information. like complete trace with --trace

Comment: i have edited my post with --trace.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just didn't ran `bundle install` after specifying `gem 'delayed_job'` in the `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'delayed_job'
```

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Resolving dependencies...
```